# how to make a tkinter program with a login input, an input area, and a submit button

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have no idea that how to make a program in python the makes a login input, an input area, and a submit button and saves to these variables:

```
e_id = #email id
pw =  # password
sv =  #the input
```

Comment: What is input panel?

Comment: I mean a input area.

Comment: tkinter has textvariables in input boxes normally, i will check docs quick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a code that seems complex but do the thing. The function `get` will run on submit button and will define the variables:

<sup>*As you said, the input is converted into a dropdown list*</sup>

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
tk.Label(text="Email: ").grid(row=0,column=0)
tk.Label(text="Password: ").grid(row=1,column=0)
tk.Label(text="Server: ").grid(row=2,column=0)
e = tk.Entry()
p = tk.Entry(show="*")
var = tk.StringVar()
var.set("Server 1")
panel = tk.OptionMenu(root,var,"Server 1","Server 2","Server 3")
panel.config(width=15)

e.grid(row=0,column=1)
p.grid(row=1,column=1)
panel.grid(row=2,column=1)
def get():
    e_id = e.get()
    pw = p.get()
    sv = panel.get()
    print(e_id, pw, sv)
tk.Button(root, text="Submit", command = get).grid(column=1)
root.resizable(False,False)
root.mainloop()
```

Output:

[image]

<sup><sup>The entries are filled mannually</sup></sup>

Comment: maybe you could make a text saying server on the left of the text box.

Comment: And make it adjust to the screen size

Comment: @TejasJoshi What do you mean by adjusting? Everything is fine.

Comment: I mean that when the screen size is changed.

Comment: @TejasJoshi Please explain more about adjusting with screen.

Comment: @TejasJoshi I have updated the code. The window is not re-sizable now.

Comment: can you change the input area to a drop down?

Comment: @TejasJoshi Please note that don't ask for answer modification that is not told in the question.

Comment: Ok. I won't do that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181464/discussion-between-tejas-joshi-and-black-thunder).